# react-native-webview control media playback in iframe

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I'm currently working on an app that has a variety of media sources. One of them is embedded Vimeo videos using `react-native-webview` and `<iframe/>`. I'm wondering if there is any way that I can control playback of those components from ReactNative.

The issue is that I need to make sure that when another media source starts, any video that is playing within a `react-native-webview` is stopped. I have a solution for iOS, disabling in-line playback via Vimeo's `playsinline` query parameter on their video URLs. But, I'm having issues with it on Android, and there is currently a related open issue with their player.js related to this.

Is there any way to control playback within the iframe from `react-native`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who also might find themselves in a similar situation, I ended up solving this by making use of Vimeo's player.js API and injecting the necessary JS to `react-native-webview`.

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/tree/ccc4d670bf81544710b23c22910ed2f75f62696f#pause-promisevoid-passworderrorprivacyerrorerror

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/eb4e923fb012f1dcb5c5389fb1901ee84e32fa8c/docs/Reference.md#injectjavascriptstr

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/eb4e923fb012f1dcb5c5389fb1901ee84e32fa8c/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

Comment: Would have been helpful if you posted an example code snippet too. Just the links are not very helpful. Especially if the links ever stop working.

Comment: @IshitaSinha I've updated the links based on your feedback. I'm not really sure what else you might want given the description I gave and the content at the links, the snippets from the docs are pretty much verbatim what I ended up using iirc. I would recommend looking at the links again, everything is there.